# react state sets to null after redirecting from another page using history() and later updates to the correct value - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I get this error when the profile page(redirects from login) finishes loading 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'email' of null'.
Can someone explain how I could wait for the state to set before executing another code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onAuthState` listener like here:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
```

You can find more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged).

Comment: Already did that but when I try to match the url param user Id and the database user Id i get the above error(cannot read property email) because it is null but how do i make it wait for the currentUser state to be set?                                                                                                                                                          db.collection('Users').where('email', "==", currentUser.email).get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data()
           setUser(Data) .........

Comment: Do you check if user is not `null`. The value can be `null`. Because of that the snipped also has the check for it. Also don't use the auth.currentUser here. Use the `user`  you get in the listener callback.